# Excel: Ignore text in a cell, count only number in the cell

Tags: excel

I have a range of cells I need to average. Most cells contain 0, 1, or 0.5. Some cells contain something like "0 - absent" or "0.5 - late". I would like to include these cells in the average, however the text complicates it. What formula can I use to count only the numbers in order to get an average?

Comment: can you guarantee each line has a # space - space text format?

Comment: This question should perhaps be moved to Superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula will produce the average you want if your data contain no blank cells. For simplicity, I've assumed your data are in the range A1:A6.

```
  =AVERAGE(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A6,SEARCH(" ",A1:A6)-1)),A1:A6))
```

[image: Spreadsheet Image]

If you do have blank cells in the data range, the formula should be modified to:

```
  =AVERAGE(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A6),"",IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A6,SEARCH(" ",A1:A6)-1)),A1:A6)))
```

[image: Formula to handle data with blanks]

These are array formulas and would need to be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

Comment: This is good, except if I have blank cells (which will be filled in in the future) it counts them as part of the average. How would I get around that?

Comment: See my amended answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem you're having? I tested your formula in Google Spreadsheets and in Excel (with the ARRAYFORMULA function removed) and got the same answer as with the original Excel formula.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realized it was user-error. I had set the cells to plain text rather than a number, and therefore they weren't being counted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach; but it requires the use of an additional column
note the formula is listed up top and it assumes consistent mask of fields with text data of # space dash space text.  you have to do an math function to convert the string data to text data or it is excluded in the avg; thus the *1 in the formula when text data is present.

[image]